# InsertAll using C# not working

Tags: google-bigquery

I´d like to know why this code is not working. It runs without errors but rows are not inserted. I´m using C# client library.

Any ideas? Thanks!!

```
string SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "(myserviceaccountemail)";
  string SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = @"C:\(myprivatekeyfile)";
  System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 certificate = 
  new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH, "notasecret",
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);


             ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
               new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
               {
                    Scopes = new[] { BigqueryService.Scope.BigqueryInsertdata, BigqueryService.Scope.Bigquery }
               }.FromCertificate(certificate));



            // Create the service.
        var service = new BigqueryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "test"

        });

    Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2.Data.TableDataInsertAllRequest tabreq = new Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2.Data.TableDataInsertAllRequest();

    List<Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2.Data.TableDataInsertAllRequest.RowsData> tabrows = new List<Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2.Data.TableDataInsertAllRequest.RowsData>();
    Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2.Data.TableDataInsertAllRequest.RowsData rd = new Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2.Data.TableDataInsertAllRequest.RowsData();
    IDictionary<string,object> r = new Dictionary<string,object>();
    r.Add("campo1", "test4");
    r.Add("campo2", "test5");
    rd.Json = r;

    tabrows.Add(rd);
    tabreq.Rows = tabrows;

service.Tabledata.InsertAll(tabreq, "(myprojectid)", "spots", "spots");
```

Comment: You are missing .execute and  `tabreq.Rows = tabrows`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add the Kind field [1]. It should be something like this:

```
tabreq.Kind = "bigquery#tableDataInsertAllRequest";
```

Also remeber that every request of the API has a response [2] with additional info to help you find the issue's root cause.

`var requestResponse = service.Tabledata.InsertAll(tabreq, "(myprojectid)", "spots", "spots");`

[1] https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Bigquery_1_1v2_1_1Data_1_1TableDataInsertAllRequest.html#aa2e9b0da5e15b158ae0d107378376b26

[2] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tabledata/insertAll